# Java : map POST body with List <Interface>

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, request

I am trying to send parameters from Front-end to Back End via a Request POST with a body (GET won't solve the problem).

Front-End side, paramaters are represented by an array of object :

```
[{Foo1 : 'bar1', Foo2 : 'bar2' ...]
```

Back-end side, paramaters are represented a list of interface :

```
List<FooInterface>
```

The problem is : i don't succed in mapping my JSON object from the body with the expected

```
List<FooInterface>.
```

Back-end side, i got an empty ArrayList instead, without error, even if the parameters are succesfully send from Front-End.

Without the list of interface, everything is fine. Mapping the list of interface is the only problem.

I tried the following methods without sucess :

- `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs=Foo.class)` on the property List `<FooInterface>`
- `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs=Foo.class)` on the `List<FooInterface>` getter
- `@JsonDeserialize(as=Foo.class)` on the `FooInterface` definition

Front-End : Angular 6

Back-End : JAVA SpringBoot

Comment: spring probably doesn't find the class which should be used as a `FooInterface`

Comment: You need to add more details. What is FooInterface. What are the implementations available for it? and how do you wish to map or what is your desired result